# How to replace uppercase letters by their lowercase counterparts?

Tags: replace, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have a big text document in which suspension points are followed by a capital letter. It should be lowercase. Now I figured to use this expression in search & replace: `…\ [:upper:]` which works fine to find the parts I want to replace, but when I try to do that with `…\ [:lower:]` I pastes literally that expression rather than the same letter but lowercase. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `[:lower:]` this way, because it's only a **pattern to match the search text**; it doesn't affect or transform the matched text part.

To solve your issue:

1. Put the search pattern in round brackets. This makes the current matched text available for the replacement pattern.
2. Reference the current match in the replacement pattern using `$1` (assuming there's only one pair of round brackets in your search pattern);
3. Tell LO Writer to use lower-case characters when replacing.

Step by step (the following example will simply replace every upper-case letter by its lower-case counterpart):

1. Open find/replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or Menu Edit -> Find/Replace...)
2. As search pattern, enter `([:upper:])`
3. Make sure that "Regular expressions" is selected in "Other Options";
4. As replace pattern, enter `$1` (this simply uses the complete current match as replacement);
5. Still with cursor in the "Replace" input box, hit the <kbd>Format...</kbd> button; this will open the "Replace with Formatting" window.
6. In the "Replace with Formatting" window, select "Font effects", and from "Effects" -> "Case", select "lowercase". Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.
7. Execute the Find/Replace.